# MySite 2013 Calendar app?

Tags: 2013, mysite

Is there a way to add a calendar app in MySite 2013? I don't need an Outlook calendar... I just need the default SharePoint Calendar App. I'm able to add a Document Library, but no other apps are available to add to my MySite. I wasn't sure if there was a setting in Central Admin that needed to be activated in order for more apps to be accessible in MySite.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `Calendar` app accessible, out-of-the-box `Team Collaboration Lists` (`Web` scope) feature have to be activated.